# How do I configure Distributed Transactions on AWS RDS?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, distributed-transactions

I'm trying to use MSSQL Server on RDS for my ASP.NET MVC site. Unfortunately due to the way the Membership provider works (doesn't provide me with access to the transaction its using) I have to use a `TransactionScope` when creating an account to avoid the race conditions and potential failures resulting in inconsistent state (when I create a new account for the website I also want to make other changes to the database).

However because the transaction is across two different connections I need distributed transactions to be configured. This is fine if I'm just using a VM but if I try using RDS then I can't seem to find a mechanism to configure it.

I've added port 135 to the security group to let it through and I'm pretty sure I've configured it correctly (ish) on the webserver/dev box. So I'm now left with the following error.

> *The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.*

Which I'm assuming means that the RDS server has not got this option configured but I am at a loss as to how to configure this. My Google fu appears to be especially weak on these search terms (rds, aws, distrubuted transactions, MSSQL Server). I'm not getting any nice hits D:.

UPDATE: I've bumped into [this](http://uksqlexperts.com/2012/07/24/sql-server-limitations-on-amazon-rds/) article which states it wasn't supported back in July.... so perhaps its not supported yet. If anyone knows if there has been an update on the status of this then let me know!

Comment: Since RDS is a commoditized database service, you may run into configurations that will not work. Sometimes support is added later, but its not something I would count on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that at present distributed transactions are not supported on RDS.

Comment: Yes they are not supported: `The following Microsoft SQL Server features are not supported on Amazon RDS: ...Distribution Transaction Coordinator (MSDTC)` documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.FeatureNonSupport